# Mongodb Time Series operations and generation

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I've got a Mongodb Collection with this kind of docs :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53cb898bed4bd6c24ae07a9f"),
"account" : "C1"
"created_on" : ISODate("2014-10-01T01:23:00.000Z")
"value" : 253
}
```

and

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52cb898bed4bd6c24ae06a9e"),
"account" : "C2"
"created_on" : ISODate("2014-10-01T01:23:00.000Z")
"value" : 9381
}
```

There is a document every minutes for C1 and C2.

I would like to generate data for an other account "C0" which will be equal to : (C2 - C1)*0.25
So the aim is to generate data for every minutes in the collection.

According to you, is it possible to do that in mongo shell ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: How do you generate these two documents (C1, C2) ?

Comment: I don't generate them, I just downloaded a database which is totally manage by tier system.

Answer (score 2):

The logic to solve this problem, is as below:

```
 a) group all the records by created_on date.
 b) get the value of both the documents in each group.
 c) calculate the difference the C2 and C1 documents for each group.
 d) In case one of the documents is missing difference 
    would be the value of the existing document.
 d) project a document with value as (difference*.25) in each group.
 e) insert the projected document to the collection.
```

I would like to propose two solutions to this, the first one would be on your assumption,

> *There is a document every minutes for C1 and C2.*

So `for every created_on` time, there would be `only two` documents,  `C1` and `C2`.

```
db.time.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        "account" : {
            $in : [ "C1", "C2" ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        "_id" : "$created_on",
        "first" : {
            $first : "$value"
        },
        "second" : {
            $last : "$value"
        },
        "count" : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "value" : {
            $multiply : [ {
                $cond : [ {
                    $lte : [ "$count", 1 ]
                }, "$first", {
                    $subtract : [ "$first", "$second" ]
                } ]
            }, 0.25 ]
        },
        "created_on" : "$_id",
        "account" : {
            $literal : "C0"
        }
    }
} ]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.value = Math.abs(doc.value);
    db.time.insert(doc);
});
```

The second solution is based on real-time scenarios. For a particular `created_on` time, there can be `'n'` number of C1 documents and `'m'` number of `C2` documents with different values, but we would need only `one` `'C0'` document representing the differences, for that particular `created_on` time.  You would need an extra `$group` pipeline operator as below:

```
db.time.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        "account" : {
            $in : [ "C1", "C2" ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        "_id" : {
            "created_on" : "$created_on",
            "account" : "$account"
        },
        "created_on" : {
            $first : "$created_on"
        },
        "values" : {
            $sum : "$value"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        "_id" : "$created_on",
        "first" : {
            $first : "$values"
        },
        "second" : {
            $last : "$values"
        },
        "count" : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        "_id" : 0,
        "value" : {
            $multiply : [ {
                $cond : [ {
                    $lte : [ "$count", 1 ]
                }, "$first", {
                    $subtract : [ "$first", "$second" ]
                } ]
            }, 0.25 ]
        },
        "created_on" : "$_id",
        "account" : {
            $literal : "C0"
        }
    }
} ]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.value = Math.abs(doc.value);
    db.time.insert(doc);
});
```